# C++ Template: how string is interpreted by compiler if i give string as parameter for Template function

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T, class T2>
T2 sum(T2 a, T b) {

T2 sum;
cout << a;// value i am getting when printed aa -> 24929 ab-> 24930
sum = a + b;
return sum;
}

void main() {
//cout << sum(2, 4);
cout << sum('aa', 'b');
}
```

Comment: `'aa'` is not a string _and_ not valid.  `'b'` in this case would be interpreted as `char`

Comment: `void main` is not legal C++. You need better learning material.